# How to block facebook in iBall router?

Tags: router, blocking

I use iBall Baton router. Its product code is iB WRA 150N. I want to block facebook in it. So I typed 192.168.1.1 in my browser and entered username and password to reach the page of iBall.

There I got confused. I have no idea where to go and what to do. After a long search I find a page which comes under Filter section. I don't know what to do there. Can anyone tell me how to block facebook ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are the steps.

1. Enter 192.168.1.1 in a browser and enter username and password(both may be admin).
2. Now click on Access Management.
3. Choose filter.
4. Change the first drop down list to URL Filter.
5. Then fill the fields in the appearing page. It includes entering the URL you want to block and you have to enter 0.0.0.0 in the following 2 fields.
6. Then Save and its done.

Comment: The above method isn't working for me. Should the active tab be switched to yes or no ? Though switching to either doesn't block any site. What should be the rule type ?
By @Samy